# MacBook Pro 2017 - suspicious network settings I don't understand

Tags: macos, network, proxy

I've been looking at my network preferences and I am concerned that these settings mean someone may be spying on me.

Can someone explain what proxies are and what does *bypass proxy* mean? And, should I be concerned about the Passive FTP Mode that is enabled?

I don't know what to look for or what are red flag as far as the entries for hosts and domains.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot doesn't indicate anything suspicious.

Most Macs will, by default, have the **Use Passive FTP Mode (PASV)** checkbox selected, so you need not be concerned about this.

In addition, most Macs will also have entries like yours in the *Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains* field.

In a nutshell, if your computer is connected to a network that has a firewall<sup>1</sup> in place, you may need to specify proxy servers<sup>2</sup> and/or select the **Use Passive FTP Mode (PASV)** checkbox to access some Internet sites.

<sup>1 A 'firewall' is designed to protect computers from unwanted/unauthorised network/Internet connections</sup>

<sup>2 A proxy server is a computer on a local network that serves as a 'middle man' between users and the Internet. It is designed to increase security and provide other administrative functions.</sup>